# Is this a good practice to avoid constant object creation?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, operators, operator-overloading

Good morning,

Say I have a class `ClassA`, an operator `+` which sums up two objects of type `ClassA`, an implicit casting from `int`to `ClassA`, and that I want to overload the operator `++`... Supposing the code for `+` is rather long, but that the sum of a `ClassA` and `1` is a very particular case of it, which option is better?

1. Implement `++` using `+` and the implicit casting already defined.
2. Repeat part of the code which simplifies alot when adding just `1`.

My idea is that (2) is better since it saves the creation of a new `ClassA` object by the implicit casting, which can be quite useful if the `++` operator is used, for example, in a `for` cycle. Also, speed is a must.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have anything against salutations? Why did you edit the post to remove it? I didn't ask that from you...

Comment: Not that I personally agree with removing the salutation, but I think it was done because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Miguel: The policy here is generally against salutations. The feeling is that they are just superfluous "noise" and don't add any particular value to posts. They are often removed by those with edit privileges. You shouldn't take it as an insult if that happens to you. You can read the discussion we had a while back about it [here on the Meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You may be right, but I think that's a matter of education... I personally hate when people start talking to me without even saying "hi" or something...

Comment: Please stop editing the salutation. If the OP wants it, it should be left: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/2960#2960

Comment: It's good to go straight to the point. everyone here presses for time.

Comment: In general, yes, but we're also all humans and it takes an extra half second to skip past it. If the questioner feels it is important, then it's ok to keep a bit of human element here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way is acceptable. It sounds like the second way is what you're already leaning towards, so try it. In fact, try it both ways and measure the time it takes to increment a million times. Benchmarking is always the way to make these decisions.

In case you haven't done any benchmarking before, the simplest way is to create a [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) and start/stop it around the relevant code. You can then write the elapsed time to a console.

Answer (score 4):

You've answered your own question. If speed is a must, then go with the second, faster option (it's a good idea to benchmark it to make sure it really is significantly faster though).

Otherwise, go with the first option since less code is better (and staying [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) doubly-so). Less code means less potential bugs, less to maintain, less to write, and less to read. If the code largely duplicates another section of code, then you'd have to keep the two in sync as you make changes -- this would be inviting trouble, as it's easy to forget to update one (and even if you always remember to make changes to both places, since they're not exactly identical it's possible to correctly update one section and incorrectly update the other).

Make sure speed really is a must though before making your final decision -- you don't want  [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that if +1 is a real special case that is much simpler, do the special ++ implementation. You can always comment it out and refer it to + 1 if you want to keep your code small.

Otherwise, it will be too easy to forget about this special optimization 6 mo. down the road when you are trying to optimize.

Premature optimization refers to the fact that you are optimizing *before* you know how to, not when you have a clear rationale to do so.  How to draw the line is difficult, however; you'd need to decide how *much* simpler the ++ code is in order to consider putting it in.